# Overlap border and text / Text overlaps image

Tags: html, css, image, text, overlap

I want to style a nav with a border that overlaps the text, and a text that overlaps an image in order to achieve the layout in the example below.

I tried different methods but nothing worked

Example:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PADgN.png)

here is what I got so far:

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGsPX.jpg)

```css
.menu-link {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px white solid;
}

.menu-link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.intro-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.intro-image::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro-block">
  <div class="intro-text">
    <h1>Front-End Developer <br />UI Designer</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-right">
    <ul class="hero-menu">
      <li class="menu-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-link"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li class="menu-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="intro-image">
      <img src="./images/heroimg.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried using "position: absolute" for the hero text but the image moves to the left.

for the navigation, I'm thinking of adding an element to HTML to contain the nav links and put a position absolute on it instead of adding border in CSS, maybe?

Is there anyway to achieve this layout? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The snippet you posted looks nothing like the image you posted. I think you left some styling out.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your elements a fixed width and height. With negative position values you can make it go outside the box. I don't know if this is what you are looking for:

html:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Projects</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#wrapper
{
  position:absolute;
  right:150px;
}

.box
{
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.box h1
{
  position:absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top:-18px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cm03bjex/21/

The `position:relative` makes sure that the absolute position is relative to the box not the whole screen.